# Python Shell Script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to understand some basic shell scripting. I have a `script.sh`, did the chmod, and was messing around with some pretty easy print statements by executing ./script.sh

Now how could I launch the shell displaying a prompt that includes the current working directory, and said prompt should accept a line of input and display a prompt each time?

To sum up the tools I understand so far: `os.getcwd()`, `sys.stdin.readlines()`, `subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subproccess.PIPE)`

Here is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ls'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cwd = os.getcwd()
while True:
user_input = raw_input(str(cwd) + " >> ")
   if user_input == 'ls':
      print proc
   if not foo:
      sys.exit()
```

So this seems to work. At least the command prompt part, not exiting.

Comment: Are you using Python to execute a shell script (sh, bash, etc.)? Are you trying to prompt the user from Python or from the shell script? Is this a question asking for Python code or shell script (sh, bash, etc.) code?

Comment: I'm confused as well and lazy to answer all the possible options hehe :-)

Comment: I am trying to create a python shell and trying to prompt the user from the script. The user should be able to type a command such as ls with no arguments. The shell will launch it, block until it completes, and then resume. If the command exits with a non-zero exit status code, then display a message to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prompt the user, then you probably don't want to be using  `sys.stdin.readlines()` as there isn't really an easy way to put your prompt in after each line. Instead, use `input()` (or `raw_input()` on Python 2).

```
user_input = input("My prompt text> ")
```

Then the user's input will be stored in a string in `user_input`. Put that in a while loop, and you can have it repeatedly display, like a regular command prompt.

Comment: basically, `while user_input:`? I think this helps a lot

Comment: You can do that if you want. You'll just have to be sure to set `user_input` before the loop starts.